# C# - Install .Net framework4

Tags: c#

I want to ask about .net framework4 . it take along time through installing, is there a way to shorten the time of installing .

for example, can I make program to install it manually by installing only dlls that I use in my application?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Can you expand?

Comment: i mean . can i install only couple of .net dlls not all of them to shortem the time of installing.

Comment: Isn't there a custom option where you get to select the packages to be installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer is no; you cannot pick and choose which .NET DLL files to include as part of your code in order to reduce the size of the install.

However, having said that, there are some tools out there which will merge assemblies together into one file. But I don't know if that scales to including all required .NET assemblies. I doubt it very much.

Comment: but i see in some common applications , there is some thing called "common framework"

Comment: Hmmm, not sure what that could mean. Where have you read about this "Common Framework"? It could be you may have confused it with "Common Language Runtime" which is the virtual machine part of .NET.

Comment: i see it when installing McAfee antivirus.

Comment: I think that's a red-herring mate.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no.

If you are writing a client-side application, then you have the option of targeting the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile if you want to. This would be a smaller install (if implemented correctly).

However, the best solution in my opinion would be to require .NET Framework 4 as a *prerequisite* for your app, rather than attempting to bundle it. It's much easier, quicker and more reliable for an end-user or system administrator to obtain .NET themselves from Windows Update or other trusted source, then install your app later.

Comment: You do realize he's talking about long install time, which probably means that he's already detected in his installer not present I need to install. Now if he asked about installer size ...

Comment: @Joshua: Yes I do, and I stand by my answer. I have personal experience of configuring setup bootstrap exes to kick off a .NET Framework download, and it's a nightmare of failed connections, retries, setup getting confused about what state the prerequisite is in, endless reboots and retries, etc etc. There is no way to make it foolproof enough. Contrast that with a simple 2-step manual process: 1 - install .NET, 2 - install the app. It's actually shorter!

Comment: What's funny about that is I've got it working to autodownload and install .NET 4. I still ship a fat installer because some customers deny internet connectivity.

Comment: Perhaps I've just been unlucky... :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use .NET 2, see Salamander linker. Disclaimer: not for all projects.